# sql - grouping matched value from 3 column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table called trx_data, lets say it contains:

```
issuer  acquirer    destination
A       A           C
A       B           A
B       A           A
B       A           C
C       B           A
A       B           C
```

i want to group A,B,C into:

> 1. value as issuer only
> 2. value as acquirer only
> 3. value as destination only
> 4. value as issuer & destination
> 5. value as issuer & acquirer
> 6. value as acquirer & destination

this is my code

```
select bank_role, count(*) from(
select
issuer,acquirer,destination,
case
when issuer="A" and acquirer="A" and destination<>"A" then "A as issuer-acquirer"
when issuer="A" and acquirer<>"A" and destination="A" then "A as issuer-destination"
when issuer<>"A" and acquirer="A" and destination="A" then "A as acquirer-destination"
when issuer="A" and acquirer<>"A" and destination<>"A" then "A as issuer only"
when issuer<>"A" and acquirer="A" and destination<>"A" then "A as acquirer only"
when issuer<>"A" and acquirer<>"A" and destination="A" then "A as destination only"
else "unknown"
end as bank_role
from trx_data
union all
select
issuer,acquirer,destination,
case
when issuer="B" and acquirer="B" and destination<>"B" then "B as issuer-acquirer"
when issuer="B" and acquirer<>"B" and destination="B" then "B as issuer-destination"
when issuer<>"B" and acquirer="B" and destination="B" then "B as acquirer-destination"
when issuer="B" and acquirer<>"B" and destination<>"B" then "B as issuer only"
when issuer<>"B" and acquirer="B" and destination<>"B" then "B as acquirer only"
when issuer<>"B" and acquirer<>"B" and destination="B" then "B as destination only"
else "unknown"
end as bank_role
from trx_data
union all
select
issuer,acquirer,destination,
case
when issuer="C" and acquirer="C" and destination<>"C" then "C as issuer-acquirer"
when issuer="C" and acquirer<>"C" and destination="C" then "C as issuer-destination"
when issuer<>"C" and acquirer="C" and destination="C" then "C as acquirer-destination"
when issuer="C" and acquirer<>"C" and destination<>"C" then "C as issuer only"
when issuer<>"C" and acquirer="C" and destination<>"C" then "C as acquirer only"
when issuer<>"C" and acquirer<>"C" and destination="C" then "C as destination only"
else "unknown"
end as bank_role
from trx_data)zxc
group by bank_role
;
```

i know this is not good, any better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all your `UNION` into single query like following.

```
select
issuer,acquirer,destination,
case
when issuer= acquirer and issuer <> destination then  issuer + " is issuer-acquirer"
when issuer = destination and acquirer <> destination  then issuer +" as issuer-destination"
when issuer<> acquirer and acquirer= destination then acquirer + " as acquirer-destination"
when issuer<> acquirer and issuer <> destination then issuer +" as issuer only"
when issuer<>acquirer and destination <> acquirer then acquirer + " as acquirer only"
when issuer<>destination and acquirer<>destination then destination + " as destination only"
else "unknown"
end as bank_role
from trx_data
```

**EDIT**: To handle different scenario, i have created a sample, it's in SQL Server, but it should work in all the database.

```
select *,
case 
when issuer=t.Identifier and acquirer=t.Identifier and destination<>t.Identifier then t.Identifier +' as issuer-acquirer'
when issuer=t.Identifier and acquirer<>t.Identifier and destination=t.Identifier then t.Identifier +' as issuer-destination'
when issuer<>t.Identifier and acquirer=t.Identifier and destination=t.Identifier then t.Identifier + ' as acquirer-destination'
when issuer=t.Identifier and acquirer<>t.Identifier and destination<>t.Identifier then t.Identifier +' as issuer only'
when issuer<>t.Identifier and acquirer=t.Identifier and destination<>t.Identifier then t.Identifier + ' as acquirer only'
when issuer<>t.Identifier and acquirer<>t.Identifier and destination=t.Identifier then t.Identifier + ' as destination only'
else 'unknown'
end as bank_role


from @trx_data d
cross join
(
 select distinct issuer as 'Identifier' from @trx_data
 union 
 select distinct acquirer as 'Identifier' from @trx_data
 union 
 select distinct destination as 'Identifier' from @trx_data
)t
order by t.Identifier
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/TWQ2297)

Comment: it doesn't work, when issuer=A, acquirer=B, and destination=C, it will return only "A as issuer only", what i want is to return "A as issuer only", "B as acquirer only", and "C as destination only"

Comment: you need to play with the conditions, i feel that you should be able to do it in single case for sure.

Comment: the problem is, there is a lot of value (not only A,B,C) , is there any optimization for that instead of using single case statement for all values?

Comment: If you need to check 5 different conditions you have check all in your query. If you can share some sample data and expected result, you might get some more optimization

Comment: @galih, i have updated the answer with the approach, you can have a look you can also check https://rextester.com/TWQ2297